# Can't turn Azure VM On using Portal Page

Tags: azure

I always get that error. What can i do?

[image: error ss]

Answer (score 0):

The VM might be in a failed state. You can try to reapply the VM. Look for Redeploy + reapply under the Support + troubleshooting tab.

Comment: I cound't do it. it said "Failed to redeploy the virtual machine 'japanwestcece'. Error: There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments."